# How do I still play sound the iphone(ipod touch) is locked but my program is running?

Tags: iphone, audio

How do I still play sound the iphone(ipod touch) is locked but my program is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];

// Use this code instead to allow the app sound to continue to play when the screen is locked.
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are playing a sound, setting the audio session type to media player before you start playing sound and before the device is locked may help.